# wordpress create a new file which can get data from wordpress and use functions

Tags: xml, wordpress, export

I'm making the export xml file from admin wordpress. In a custom admin page I built , it have a button to export xml file.

The export button will go to a url of export file , which will get data and display as xml file.

The problem is that wordpress does not allow to create a new file which can get data and use function of wordpress.

The export function is the part of a custom wordpress theme, so the export file must be predefined! I can create a wordpress page template to export data. but it need to create a new page and use the export page template.

I can create a wordpress admin page , but it look like alway to load admin screen, so it can't be turn into a xml file.

The content of export xml file is almost data from wordpress options and a custom database which theme built!

Anyone have idea to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer you want to hear, but code it yourself. I had to create a plugin to generate a JSON file, but I have the plugin linked up to when the Publish button is pushed. PHP has an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) that may help you (PHP's JSON parser works for my purposes).